# AngularJs Formly - Dynamically add wrapper

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have several field types that I have created.  They are similar to each other except their wrappers are different.  One type may need wrapped in something that the other does not need (thus the multiple types were created).

Is it possible to pass wrappers to field types?  Maybe something like this:

```
vm.fields=[
    {
        key: 'name',
        type: 'fieldType1'
        wrappers: ['wrapper1', 'wrapper2']
    }
]
```

I am trying to use the least amount of field types for the sake of supporting this in the future.  If the only difference between these types are the wrapper...I am hoping that I can inject the wrappers that I want into the type when I add the field to my field array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually define `wrapper` as a field property ([docs](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object#wrapper-string--array-of-strings)), like so:

```
vm.fields=[
    {
        key: 'name',
        type: 'fieldType1'
        wrapper: ['wrapper1', 'wrapper2']
    }
]
```

(Notice, the only difference between this example and your code is it's `wrapper` not `wrappers`).

I realize (and apologize) that the name is confusing, but for what it's worth, you can specify a string or array of strings, so it would make sense in this case:

```
vm.fields=[
    {
        key: 'name',
        type: 'fieldType1'
        wrapper: 'wrapper1'
    }
]
```

Comment: Doh, `wrapper` makes total sense.  I must have just blindly added the '`s`' when I was trying to figure this out.  Thanks Kent!

Comment: Kent, one of the wrappers that I am using does custom stuff with the label placement.  This works fine with the wrapper is within the field type.  However, when I move the wrapper within the field array, the label is listed twice (once because of my wrapper and once because of the default label that formly normally adds).  Is there a good way to hide the normal label from formly?  It is odd that the label appears once the wrappers are added to the field array.

Comment: Nevermind.  I think this was happening since the field type no longer had a wrapper on it (so it used the default formly label).  If I set the wrapper within the fields array but still set the wrapper equal to `null` within the field type...all is good.